# Rational points of modular curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

What is known and not known about rational points of modular curves? What are some good references?

Comment: Could you make the question more specific? Do you mean $\mathbb{Q}$ or an arbitrary number field or what? Which modular curves $X_0(N),X_1(N),X(N)$ or some other? Good reference is Mazur, B., Modular curves and the Eisenstein ideal. Inst. Hautes Études Sci. Publ. Math. No. 47 (1977), 33--186.

Comment: Loic Merel's work from the mid-90s generalises some of Mazur's results to arbitrary number fields. See also Edixhoven's Seminaire Bourbaki talk from around the same time. But this question is ridiculously vague.

Comment: "What is known?" A lot; "and not known?" Also a lot.

Comment: A nice reference for Merel's result is the Clay Proceedings: http://math.univ-bpclermont.fr/~rebolledo/page-fichiers/07-goettingen.pdf It also touches on related work of Mazur, Kamienny, Kenku, Momose, Parent and others. If we allow ourselves to move slightly outside the classical modular curves, we get lots of other interesting results, including the Bilu-Parent result on $X_{split}(p)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dear Dick,

I am going to interpret *rational points* to mean points over $\mathbb Q$.

Given this,
Mazur's *Eisenstein ideal* paper, his *rational isogenies* paper, and various surveys
he wrote around that time (mid-to-late 1970s) give a good description (and also prove
the most of the key results).

Ogg also wrote surveys in the early 70s, making conjectures which Mazur then proved,
which are very helpful.  You'll easily find them on mathscinet (as you will with Mazur's 
papers and surveys).

Best wishes,

Matt